# How to retrieve rows from the table using Protractor?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, selenium, protractor, automated-tests

I am using protractor for my UI test. I am trying to retrieve and validate the rows from the table.
Below is my code. The issue I have here is , It returns each row in the table when I do console.log but when I do expect to validate with rows. Its validating with empty values. I am using async.series for my flow. below function is part of my async. Each row has the value "SDY789".

```
function(callback){
            element.all(by.tagName("tr")).each(function(row,index){
                row.getText().then(function(text){
                    console.log("print text************"+text);
                    expect(text).toContain("SDY789");
                })
            })
            callback();
        },

This is what i am getting with as a  result.

print text************06-15-2016 james SDY789 28 Male
print text************
print text************04-15-2011 williams SDY789 56 Male
print text************
print text************10-14-2003 harry SDY789 32 Male
print text************
print text************12-14-2004 elliot SDY789 41 Male
print text************
print text************02-14-2005 andy SDY789 28 Male

Expected '' to contain 'SDY789'.
Expected '' to contain 'SDY789'.
Expected '' to contain 'SDY789'.
Expected '' to contain 'SDY789'.
Expected '' to contain 'SDY789'.
```

Please also suggest how to retrieve specific column only. The table is not using ng-repeat so I cannot use repeater control from Protractor.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by targeting the specific column and able to retrieve the data from the specific column.

```
function(callback){
        element.all(by.tagName("table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(4)")).each(function(row,index){
            row.getText().then(function(text){
                console.log("print text************"+text);
                expect(text).toContain("SDY789");
            })
        })
callback();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit simplified code:

```
var table = $$('table tr');
table.each(function(row) {
  var rowElems = row.$$('td');
  expect(rowElems.count()).toBe(4);
  expect(rowElems.get(3).getText()).toContain("SDY789");
});
```